# s pen: rotation sensitive?

Tags: samsung

I know, this is not 100% an android question. But maybe someone can help me. I'm trying to figure out, if the pen, that comes with the Samsung Galaxy Note Pro 12.2 Tablet is rotation sensitive.
And if not, is there a pen compatible to this device that is rotation sensitive?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  Rotating a point or circle (like a pen tip) has no effect.

Comment: imagine in a drawing program you use a tool with a tip that is not a circle. rotating the pen would then change it's direction. I have the tablet here and I don't see this feature, but maybe it's just not implemented in the software, but the hardware is capable to do so. well, unlikely..

Comment: Makes sense.  Upon doing some research it looks like that device was launched after the Note 4, which [included an S Pen that supported rotation](http://pocketnow.com/2014/11/13/new-s-pen).  I can't imagine that they would have removed that feature....

Comment: I read something like this as well. It's really hard to find out detailed specs about this..